# Locus of circumcentre

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, and $P$ a variable point on its circumcircle. Suppose $AP$ meets $BC$ at $Q$. What is the locus of the circumcentre of $\triangle BPQ$?

Experiments on GeoGebra show that the locus is a line through $B$, but I am struggling to identify this line, or see anything geometrically significant in the diagram. Could someone help me to prove this synthetically? Thank you.

Comment: The oriented angle $\angle BPQ$ remains constant modulo $\pi$, so all the circumcircles have the same tangent at $B$.

Comment: ah i see: then the locus of $O$ is the line perpendicular to this tangent at $B$: thanks a lot!